How can I control the camera flashlight strength from android 13 in Jetpack compose app
I see some open-source flashlight apps (FlashDim , Flashlight-Tiramisu) that can control flash strength from Android version 13+, but these apps build using Kotlin and XML (not in jetpack compose). So I wanted to develop same type of app but the problem is, I cant control the flash strength from android 13, The error says it needs to be android 15+ (API 35+). Here's a simple function that I want to share,
@RequiresApi(35)
fun getTorchStrengthValue(context: Context) : Int {
    val cameraManager = ContextCompat.getSystemService(context, CameraManager::class.java) as CameraManager
    val cameraId = cameraManager.cameraIdList[0]
    val cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)

    val torchMaxLevel = cameraCharacteristics[CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_TORCH_STRENGTH_MAX_LEVEL] ?: -1
    return torchMaxLevel
}

As it says, the required API 35, this same system is implemented in The Flashlight-tiramisu app, (maybe in different ways of course). But there is doesn't require API 35.
How can I bypass that from my Jetpack-compose app??

You are using CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_TORCH_STRENGTH_MAX_LEVEL. That is new to API Level 35.
The app you cite is using CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_STRENGTH_MAXIMUM_LEVEL. That was added in API Level 33.
